# How to load the HSQL DB once before running all junit in Java project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, junit

My project is not Spring based .Its a java with Hibernate.Building tool - Maven.

I am loading data from one database to HSQL DB before running junits.

My DB util class:

```
public class DatabaseUtil {
    SchemaLoad schemaLoad = new SchemaLoad();
    DataLoad dataLoad = new DataLoad();
    boolean dataLoaded = false;

    static final String filename1 = "test1.txt";
    static final String filename2 = "text2.txt";

    void dbLoad() throws SQLException {
        if (!dataLoaded) {
            schemaLoad.cloneSchema(filename1);
            dataLoad.exportData(filename2);
            System.out.println("***********executed**********8");
            dataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

First Test Case:

```
public class TestCase {

    TrainRepository trainRepository = new TrainRepositoryImpl();
    DatabaseUtil databaseUtil = new DatabaseUtil();

    @BeforeClass
    private void setUp() throws SQLException {
        databaseUtil.dbLoad();

    }

    @Test
    private void positiveTestCaseForTrainRepo() throws Exception {

        //TestCases
    }
```

Second Test case:

public class TestCase1 {

```
AirRepository airRepository = new AirRepositoryImpl();
DatabaseUtil databaseUtil = new DatabaseUtil();

@BeforeClass
private void setUp() throws SQLException {
    databaseUtil.dbLoad();

}

@Test
private void positiveTestCaseForAirRepo() throws Exception {

    //TestCases
}
```

Both the test cases are running fine.But Its executing databaseUtil.dbLoad(); method on each junit.

My question is I need to load the database only once ie before start of first junit and need to set some indicator .The further junits need to check the DB instance If DB instance is there it should not load the data ie DatabaseUtil class need to be singleton.

All the junits are running through maven suffire plugin during mvn install phase.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: Are you saying dbLoad() is being invoked for each test that is part of the same test suite (so TestCase1 in this case) ? If so that shouldn't happen since BeforeClass is designed to be run once for a test suite. What you describe sounds like you have a Before annotation and not BeforeClass.

Answer (score 0):

void dbLoad() will be called each time.

then use a static variable to keep track

```
static boolean dataLoaded = false;
```

Comment: If I mark it dataload as static I am getting initialization exception on set up methodjava.lang.Exception: Method setUp() should be static

Comment: I dont understand: dataLoaded should be a static variable of DatabaseUtil, and is accessed only in dbload.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use spring you need to implement caching yourself. you have a few option. use static field with some kind of synchronization (in case you use/plan to use threads). other option is to switch to testng that gives you `@BeforeGroup` functionality so you can mark all your db tests and have your initialization run before.